# TYPO3 conditional ext_tables.sql depends on existing table

Tags: typo3

Usually if you want to extend a table for an extension you use something like this in `ext_tables.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE tt_address (
    tx_myext_field varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
);
```

But if you havn't installed tt_address the table will be created anyway. Can I prevent this?

If you aks now why I want to install an extension that extend another and want to prevent insert the table fields ;)

In my case I want to create an extension that can extend the fe_user, the tt_address and other tables. But I want that the user can deside, which he want to use. fe_users, tt_address, both or other etc. It would be perfect the user can chooese this in the ext config.

Is there any best practise for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why bother? When table `tt_address` gets created without the extension `tt_address` installed, it does not hurt anybody. Maybe you want to show a hint on ext_conf_template.txt that you need `tt_address` installed in order to use that feature.

Plan B would be to alter the DB table within some PHP Code - Backend Module or Frontend Plugin would be "worst practice". But it could work to make a update script class.ext_update.php that checks if the table already exists before adding the field. But the update function would have to be executed additionally to the database update.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about the different solutions and think I use another way. Cause I need the field for a wizard, I'll provide only the wizard and the user have to add the fields manually or provide them with the extension.